# Xcode 7.1 throwing "UI Testing Failure" when i tap on textfield or button in XCT. It worked till xcode7.0.1

Tags: xcode, xctest

```
app.buttons.elementBoundByIndex(9).tap()
app.buttons["New Sale"].tap()
/*this is the textfield i am trying to tap*/
app.textFields.elementBoundByIndex(0).pressForDuration(2)
```

Error is:

```
<unknown>: UI Testing Failure - Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) 
TextField 0x7fa3c96c02b0: traits: 146029150208, {{272.0, 315.0}, {480.0, 40.0}}, 
placeholderValue: 'Select', 
error: Error -25204 performing AXAction 2003
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by first scrolling to the element, then tapping:

```
let textField = app.textFields.elementBoundByIndex(0)
app.scrollToElement(textField)
textField.tap()
```